# Alexa skill that counts with a user specified interval

Tags: python, counter, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a skill that counts to a user specified number in user specified intervals.
For example I would say `Alexa count to 30 in intervals of 2 seconds`

I can do it in python but i am a noob when it comes to coding alexa skills. Apparently Alexa now has a python service. So i can just edit the lambda_function.py code.
How do i integrate my python script with the alexa code base?

The python code would be as simple as:

```
from time import sleep
for num in range(1, user_end):
    print(num)
    sleep(user_interval)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[APL for Audio](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-for-audio-reference.html) should allow you to create a dynamic response like this.

Here's a sample document and data source that works for me.

**Document**

```
{
    "type": "APLA",
    "version": "0.91",
    "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
            "payload"
        ],
        "item": {
            "type": "Sequencer",
            "data": "${payload.counts}",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "Speech",
                    "content": "${data}"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Silence",
                    "duration": "${payload.intervalMs}"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Data Source:**

```
{
    "counts": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30],
    "intervalMs": 2000
}
```

Your skill can piece those together an add the following **directive** to its response:

```
{
  "type": "Alexa.Presentation.APLA.RenderDocument",
  "token": "developer-provided-string",
  "document": {
    "type": "APLA",
    "version": "0.91",
    "mainTemplate": {
      "parameters": [
        "payload"
      ],
      "item": {
        "type": "Sequencer",
        "data": "${payload.counts}",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "Speech",
            "content": "${data}"
          },
          {
            "type": "Silence",
            "duration": "${payload.intervalMs}"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "datasources": {
    "counts": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7,
      8,
      9,
      10,
      11,
      12,
      13,
      14,
      15,
      16,
      17,
      18,
      19,
      20,
      21,
      22,
      23,
      24,
      25,
      26,
      27,
      28,
      29,
      30
    ],
    "intervalMs": 2000
  }
}
```

Comment: So would the max count have to be hard coded and therefore limited?

Comment: No, you do not have to hardcode the max count. You can programmatically generate the array `counts` at runtime in the data sources object you pass in the directive.  Something like `datasources = {'counts': list(range(1, maxCount + 1))}` to give you an array of values 1 to `maxCount` inclusive.